# enabled submit button if radio button field data and other field data found using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few fields on this code snippet. Here I have radio button If `Field_One` is checked show mentioned input field (country select, first name, last name, mobile, email, trans id) same like if `Field_Two` is checked show mentioned field (reference no, id no and trans id)

Here Trans ID. First Name, Last Name is mandotory for both radio button and its a required field. But I have added few required field without last name.

And `Field_Two` radio field will show field like reference id and id no. I want if only one field is required field and if only one field is filled up then its ok from both reference id and id no.

But My code is not working properly See the below snippet

One thing if First Country is Africa then show another Dropdown box with Country2 but its also required when Africa is selected but Africa not selected its not required.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        function make_required_inputs(el) {
            let value = el.val();
            let div = $('div.' + value);
            $('input[required]').removeAttr('required');
            div.find('input.required').attr('required', true);
            $('input[name="trxid"]').attr('required', true);
            
        }
        function validation() { 
            let valid = true;
            $.each($('input[required]'), function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') valid = false;
            });
            if (valid) {
                jQuery('#button1').attr('disabled', false);
            } else {
                jQuery('#button1').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        }

        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "Field_One") {
                $(".Field_One").show();
                $(".Field_Two").hide();
                $("#country").show();
            }
            if ($(this).attr("value") == "Field_Two") {
                $(".Field_Two").show();
                $(".Field_One").hide();
                $("#country").hide();
            }
            validation();
        });

        let checked = $('input[name="myfield"]:checked');
        let value_checked = checked.attr("value");
        if (value_checked == "Field_One") {
            $(".Field_One").show();
            $(".Field_Two").hide();            
        }else if (value_checked == "Field_Two") {
            $(".Field_Two").show();
            $(".Field_One").hide();
        }
        $('input[type="radio"]')
        make_required_inputs($('input[name="myfield"]:checked'));

        $('input[name="myfield"]').on('change', function () {
            make_required_inputs($(this));
            validation();
        });
        $('input').keyup(function (e) {
            validation();
        });
        
        
    jQuery("#country").change(function(){
            jQuery(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
                var optionValue = jQuery(this).attr("value");
                if(optionValue=='za'){
          jQuery("#country2").show();
                } else{
                    jQuery("#country2").hide();
                }
            });
        }).change();

        jQuery("#country2").hide();

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="myfield" value="Field_One" checked="true" /> Field_One
<input type="radio" name="myfield" value="Field_Two" /> Field_Two
<br><br>
<select name="country" class="required" id="country">
<option>Select</option>
<option value="us">US</option>
<option value="uk">UK</option>
<option value="za">Africa</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select name="country2" class="required" id="country2">
<option>Select</option>
<option value="eg">Egypt</option>
<option value="ng">Nigeria</option>
<option value="gh">Ghana</option>
<option value="za">South Africa</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="first_name" class="required" placeholder="First Name" />
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<br><br>
<div class="Field_One">
<input type="text" name="mobile_no" placeholder="Mobile no"/>
<br><br>
<input type="text" class="required" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
</div>
<br>
<div class="Field_Two">
    <input type="text" name="reference_no" class="required" placeholder="Reference no" /><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="id_no" class="required" placeholder="ID no" />
</div><br>
<input type="text" name="trxid" class="required" placeholder="Trans ID" />
<input type="submit" id="button1" value="Submit" disabled/>
```

Comment: You are assigning the value for `myfieldval` directly when the page loads, the user has not even had a _chance to modify the radio button selection yet.

Comment: You should not try and assign two different `keyup` handler functions in the first place (because then you would also have to _remove_ one again, and _add_ the other, when the radio button selection changes) - but handle both cases inside _one_ handler function.

Comment: So I need to use one `keyup` handler to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

        function validation() {
            let valid = true;
            $.each($('input[required]:not([name="reference_no"],[name="id_no"]),select[required]'), function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') valid = false;
            });
            let one = 0;
            if ($('input[one="true"][required]').length == 0) {
                one = 1;
            } else {
                one = 0;
                $.each($('input[one="true"][required]'), function () {
                    if ($(this).val() !== '') one++;
                });
            }



            if (valid && one > 0) {
                jQuery('#button1').prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                jQuery('#button1').prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
        function required(value) {
            $('input.required,select.required').prop('required', true);
            if (value == "Field_One") {
                $(".Field_One").show();
                $(".Field_Two").hide().find('input,select').prop('required', false);
                $("#country").show().addClass('required').prop('required', true);
            }
            if (value == "Field_Two") {
                $(".Field_Two").show();
                $(".Field_One").hide().find('input,select').prop('required', false);
                $("#country").hide().removeClass('required').prop('required', false);
                jQuery("#country2").hide().removeClass('required').prop('required', false);
            }
            validation();
        }

        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
            required($(this).val());
        });

        let value_checked = $('input[name="myfield"]:checked').attr("value");
        required(value_checked);



        $('select,input').on('change keyup', function () {
            validation();
        });

        jQuery("#country").change(function () {
            var optionValue = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").attr("value");
            if (optionValue == 'za') {
                jQuery("#country2").show().addClass('required').prop('required', true);;
            } else {
                jQuery("#country2").hide().removeClass('required').prop('required', false);;
            }
            validation();
        }).change();

        jQuery("#country2").hide().removeClass('required').prop('required', false);
    });
let valid2 = true;
$.each($('#domain_name,select[required]'), function () {               if ($(this).val() == '') valid2 = false;     });     if (valid2) {                 jQuery('#domsBtn').prop('disabled', false);             } else {                 jQuery('#domsBtn').prop('disabled', true);             }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="myfield" value="Field_One" checked="true" /> Field_One
<input type="radio" name="myfield" value="Field_Two" /> Field_Two
<br><br>
<select name="country" class="required" id="country">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="us">US</option>
    <option value="uk">UK</option>
    <option value="za">Africa</option>
</select>
<select name="country2" class="required" id="country2">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="eg">Egypt</option>
    <option value="ng">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="gh">Ghana</option>
    <option value="za">South Africa</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="first_name" class="required" placeholder="First Name" />
<br><br>
    <input type="submit" id="firstCheck" value="First Name Check" disabled />
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" />
<br><br>
<div class="Field_One">
    <input type="text" name="mobile_no" placeholder="Mobile no" />
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" class="required" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
</div>
<br>
<div class="Field_Two">
    <input type="text" name="reference_no" one="true" class="required" placeholder="Reference no" /><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="id_no" one="true" class="required" placeholder="ID no" />
</div><br>
<input type="text" name="trxid" class="required" placeholder="Trans ID" />
<input type="submit" id="button1" value="Submit" disabled />
```

Comment: Not working. It only works Field Two Reference id and Trxid but first checked Field One not working.

Comment: Check the update

Comment: `last_name` not required

Comment: i solved it, if you add any input you want it required, just add class required. 
check out

Comment: check my update

Comment: Reference No and ID no (both field are not mandotory if any one is filled then enabled button)

Comment: check the update again

Comment: Thanks a lot @Younes Its working properly now

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: check the update

Comment: i update my answer